# How to count the total number of lines prefetched to the L2 cache in Skylake

Tags: intel, cpu-architecture, perf

Running `perf list`, I can see an extensive list of events that [perf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux)) can capture. One of them is:

```
l2_lines_out.useless_hwpf                         
       [Counts the number of lines that have been hardware prefetched but not used and now
       evicted by L2 cache]
```

I want to obtain the total number of prefetched lines into the [L2 cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Multi-level_caches) on [Skylake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)), so I can compose the ratio of how many out of the total prefetched lines are useless. However, I cannot see any other event related that can help me in getting that total.

Comment: Does `l2_rqsts.all_pf` do what you want?  The description mentions L1 and L3 HW prefetch as well but that conflicts with its name, so IDK.  `perf list` on my Skylake says it includes software prefetch.  Possibly `l2_rqsts.pf_hit` + `l2_rqsts.pf_miss` could total all prefetch-generated requests that hit or miss in L2.

Comment: the fact that it mentions L1, L2, and L3, confuses me. If the words "L2 request" means "requests from somebody that L2 services", then `l2_reqsts.all` is the opposite of what I want. Currently I am using `l2_lines_in.all`, but that includes (or I think so) the requests on demand made **by** L2.

Comment: I think all the `l2_rqsts` events are supposed to count requests made by L2 (to L3), and the `.whatever` part is one of various a filters.  The description text might just be an editing error, worth digging into other docs to see if there's any more detailed or sensible definition somewhere.  And/or some experiments to see if it counts demand loads, or SW prefetch only into L3, not L2.  I'm optimistic about that event based on the name, but it certainly could be not what you want.  I guess `prefetcht2` instructions have to get the message to L3 somehow, and that might go through L2 on the way.

Comment: Do you have some good resource to read? I cannot find a reasonable explanation of perf events. Also, in a multicore system, L2 can perfectly make a request to L2 of another core, or L1. Therefore, L2 can also receive requests from any cache level, backing up the writing of `perf list`

Comment: In Skylake-client CPUs (and all Intel CPUs before Skylake, back to Nehalem), L3 tags contain / are the coherence "directory" that tracks which core(s) have copies or ownership of which lines.  I was under the impression that the ring-bus message from a core requesting a line would go to a slice of L3 (selected by the cache index hash function for that address), and if necessary another message would be sent from there to complete the RFO or share request.

Comment: I guess it's possible that a core could be given a hint (in an invalidate message) of which other core last requested ownership of that line, but that would have to be tracked somewhere, and L3 needs to know about the change anyway.  Perhaps keeping track of a core number in a share-request would be more possible, because the line stays valid so an RFO to regain ownership of it is more likely.  But that would add bits to every L2 tag.  IDK how much it could plausibly speed up cache-line ping pong. (And BTW, Skylake-X and later server CPUs use a mesh with a separate tag directory; similar.)

Comment: I am sorry, but still don't get what ´l2_rqsts.{all_pf,pf_hit,pf_miss}´ actually measure. The description of the later two mentions requests from somebody else, that hits or miss L2. From there, I understand that the hw prefetch was originated somewhere else.

I found [this page](https://download.01.org/perfmon/index/skylake.html) that agrees with your definition, but [this post on intel forums](https://community.intel.com/t5/Software-Tuning-Performance/Are-there-any-available-counters-for-LLC-out-prefetch-traffic-on/td-p/1134834) shows the same discrepancy between gen4 and posterior ones

Comment: I expect that the L2 streamer and spatial prefetchers fetch *through* L2, and that's how they populate it.  And naturally L1 prefetchers also fetch through L2, so they're ultimately prefetching into L2 as well as L1d / L1i.  If we can find any confirmation of that guess, the `.all_pf` event should be counting all lines requested by L2 that are due to any kind of prefetch from L1i/d or L2 prefetchers.

Comment: `l2_rqsts` counts requests *to* the L2 cache (inbound), not necessarily *by* the L2 cache (outbound). Of course, some requests, like those that miss, also result in an outbound request.